# ReactTooltip.show does not work in Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-tooltip

I want to show the tooltip based on some logic, which means I'll execute ReactTooltip.show to show the Tooltip manually.

As of now, the example in the docs mention passing the reference of the target to the function, which is not working in my case.

Here is a link to the code sandbox I created, showing a sample structure of my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/reacttooltip-sandbox-ovzfe

The click of Show tooltip 3 is not showing the tooltip on the below p tag.

Comment: there is no "Show tooltip 3" in sandbox

Comment: @Apostolos I can see the `Show tooltip3` button... check again>

Comment: yes now it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need `forwardRef`

and also you need the properties inside your paragraph

```
  <p
    ref={ref}
    data-tip="tooltip"
    data-for={props.dataFor}
    data-event="click"
  >
    This is Tooltip 3
  </p>
```

I added an extra property `dataFor` to be more customizable

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacttooltip-sandbox-forked-r9roj)

And here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacttooltip-sandbox-forked-uhfk9) with `useRef` instead of `useState`

Comment: Oh!

I should've thought of ForwardRef!

Comment: @AbhishekJain glad I helped. If it helped you, i would be grateful if you upvoted it too!